# Dojo 1.6 how to catch drag and drop 'inserNode' events

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, dojo

Trying to dynamic change DND container's height but seems not working.

`assigned_list` holds all insertions, I try to catch nodes using following method bu failed, firebug never go through this method when insert a node

```
// 'insertNodes' doesn't work
// same with onDndDrop
// firebug doesn't respond to this dojo.connect, when insert a node
dojo.connect(assigned_list, "onDndDrop", nodeChanges);
```

here is `nodeChanges` function

```
function nodeChanges(){
    dojo.byId("assigned_nodes_container").style.height = dojo.byId("assigned_nodes_container").clientHeight+'px';
}
```

We are on Dojo 1.6

Answer (score 0):

Here's my guess : try to set

```
dojo.connect('dojo.byId("assigned_list")','onDndDrop',nodeChanges);
```

and in the called function :

```
 dojo.style('assigned_nodes_container','height',dojo.byId('assigned_nodes_container').clientHeight+'px' );
```

This is a better way to set the style of a Element.

For deeper information look here :
http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.6/dojo/style.html#dojo-style

Also look here : http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/
That's the newest Version of Dojo with the new AMD Technologie.

Regards, Miriam